# How to show parallel lines UI for git branches in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

How can I show parallel branch lines in IntelliJ git logs?

[image]

This is my old project and it shows like that.

In my newer project although I have multiple branches merged to master already, still, that beautiful view isn't there, it's just the straight line appearing.

Is this an IntelliJ bug or I don't get when those lines gets showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot, the history of your repository is just linear - there are no commits that have more than a single child - that is why no other branches are in the graph.

Branches in git are in fact just a reference to a commit. So several branches can be referencing the same commit without producing any branches in the graph. This seems to be the case.

Comment: If I want to implement some feature, I create a branch for that, when I'm done, I merge it into `master`, should it be linear in this case? If not, what should I do not to make it linear?

Comment: It depends. If the commit where master reference sits is an ancestor of your branch tip, merging will just fast-forward the reference. If you want to always have a merge commit in the hisotry, you need to use the `--no-ff` option when merging. in IJ it is avaiible through hthe Git Merge dialog.

Answer (score -3):

Intellij has a plugin named GitHub, if you install it (from settings -> plugins)
you will have a 'git' tab at the bottom, inside that tab you will see the GUI you are referring to

Comment: I have that git tool window, but there are no parallel lines showing, just a single line although I have multiple branches already merged to master.

Comment: In that case, i think you have some filters set, check it on the top of the git panel: make sure you have 'Branch: All' 'User: All' and so on. If that's not the case, then I suggest you to clone again the repo

Comment: I have no filters, I've cloned again, didn't work.